# Creating rdbms DDL from scala classes

Tags: scala, orm, playframework

Is there a *straightforward* way to generate rdbms ddl, for a set of scala classes?

I.e. to derive a table ddl for each class (whereby each case class field would translate to field of the table, with a corresponding rdbms type).

Or, to directly create the database objects in the rdbms.

I have found *some* documentation about [Ebean being embedded in Play framework](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.7/JavaEbean), but was not sure what side-effects may enabling Ebean in play have, and how much taming would Ebean require to avoid any of them. I have never even used Ebean before...

I would actually rather use something outside of Play, but if it's simple to accomplish in Play I would dearly like to know a clean way. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a straightforward way to generate rdbms ddl, for a set of
>   scala classes?

Yes

1. **Ebean**

   Ebean a default orm provided by play you just have to create entity and enable evolution(which is set to enable as default).It will create a (dot)sql file in conf/evolution/default directory and when you hit [localhost:9000](http://localhost:9000) it will show you apply script .**But your tag say you are using scala so you can't really use EBean with Scala .If you do that you will have to
   sacrifice the immutability of your Scala class, and to use the Java
   collections API instead of the Scala one.**
   **Using Scala this way will just bring more troubles than using Java directly.**
   [**Source**](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/play-framework/132f913zpz/ebean-used-in-scala-project)
2. **JPA**

   JPA (using Hibernate as implementation) is the default way to access and manage an SQL database in a standard Play Java application. It is still possible to use JPA from a Play Scala application, but **it is probably not the best way**, and it should be considered as legacy and deprecated.[**Source**](https://www.playframework.com/modules/scala-0.9/database)
3. **Anorm**(if you want to write ddl)

   **Anorm is Not an Object Relational Mapper** so you have to manually write ddl. [**Source**](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaAnorm)
4. **Slick**

   Function relation mapping for scala .[**Source**](http://slick.typesafe.com/)
5. **Activate**

   Activate is a framework to persist objects in Scala.[**Source**](http://activate-framework.org/)
6. **Skinny**

   It is built upon ScalikeJDBC library which is a thin but powerful JDBC wrapper.[**Details1**](http://skinny-framework.org/documentation/orm.html),[**Details2**](http://blog.seratch.net/post/110711051753/skinny-orm-for-play-framework)

   Also check [**RDBMS with scala**](http://manuel.bernhardt.io/2014/02/04/a-quick-tour-of-relational-database-access-with-scala/),[**Best data access option for play scala**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476658/which-is-best-data-access-options-available-for-play-framework-with-scala-and-po)

Comment: Thanks!! BTW slick is not relevant here - it does not generate DDL for scala classes, only for a given existing rdbms schema. And why is anorm related? it doesn't create ddl does it?

Comment: In particular, on first look Activate looks like it does not map objects to ddl, rather you have to create a migration object for that. Can you suggest what I might be missing about using activate to generate DDL? I just don't see here an answer to `Is there a straightforward way to generate rdbms ddl, for a set of scala classes?`

Comment: @matt as far as I know slick can create ddl check http://java.dzone.com/articles/getting-started-play-21-scala and I have mentioned above that in anorm you have to create ddl

Comment: I use slick every day, it creates ddl for an existing schema. That's not the topic of the question though...

Comment: you are right about migration object in activate .`Is there a straightforward way to generate rdbms ddl, for a set of scala classes?`  yes jpa but you are not able to use case classes and some more features of scala

Comment: I think I'll use SORM. It auto-generates for nested classes according to the docs!

Comment: @matt forget to mention that but chose SORM version correctly because sometime the scala version required by SORM is different from scala version by play causing errors